# Giving attributes to nodes of a generated graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am new to Python and NetworkX and I'm trying to give attributes from a dictionary to the nodes of a network created with a graph generator. Here is my sample code:

```
g = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(5,4,0.1)

name_dict = {
  0: "Alice",
  1: "Bob",
  2: "Carl",
  3: "Diana",
  4: "Elain",
}

nx.set_node_attributes(g, name, name_dict)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, name, name_dict)
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

How do I define the name of the attribute ('name') giving values from the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

You get this error because you have no variable named `name`.

Let's look at [the documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) that I found by googling "networkx set_node_attributes":

> set_node_attributes(G, values, name=None)[source]
>
> Sets node attributes from a given value or dictionary of values.
>
> Warning
>
> The call order of arguments values and name switched between v1.x & v2.x.
>
> Parameters
>
> G (NetworkX Graph)
>
> values (scalar value, dict-like) – What the node attribute should be set to. If values is not a dictionary, then it is treated as a single attribute value that is then applied to every node in G. This means that if you provide a mutable object, like a list, updates to that object will be reflected in the node attribute for every node. The attribute name will be name.
>
> If values is a dict or a dict of dict, it should be keyed by node to either an attribute value or a dict of attribute key/value pairs used to update the node’s attributes.
>
> name (string (optional, default=None)) – Name of the node attribute to set if values is a scalar.

This tells us that the dictionary must be the second parameter to pass in, not the third as you have it.

It also tells us that the `name` argument is an optional string.

Putting this all together, you can fix your code by doing this:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(g, name_dict)
```

This will now run, but it leaves out the name of the attribute. If you want the attribute to have the name `'name'`, then you can pass a string as the third parameter:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(g, name_dict, 'name')
```

TLDR; You need to fix the order of your parameters and make `'name'` a string instead of a variable by surrounding it with quotes.